# Flutter Button Grid layout on press invokes every button

Tags: flutter, button, gridview

I have implemented a dashboard with cards making them tap enabled. I have put these cards inside a Grid layout and I tried to give each card onTap a simple animation as well. But when I try to tap a single item in the grid layout, all the items are getting invoked. Can someone help me to solve this ? I will provide my code snippets.

**The grid**

```
Widget createGridItem(int position) {
      var icondata = Icons.add;
      var title = "";

      switch (position) {
        case 0:
          icondata = Icons.pie_chart;
          break;
        case 1:
          icondata = Icons.perm_device_info;
          break;
}

return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => buttonHandler(),
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: _scale,
          child: homeEnabledButtons(
            context,
            title,
            icondata,
          ),
        ),
      );

GridView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 30,
                mainAxisSpacing: 30,
              ),
              children: [
                createGridItem(0),
                createGridItem(1),
                createGridItem(2),
                createGridItem(3),
               ], ),
```

**The Button item**

```
Widget homeEnabledButtons(
    BuildContext context, String title, IconData icon, Function fun) {
  return
      Card(
    elevation: 10.0,
    color: color,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Icon(
          icon,
          color: primaryColor,
          size: 100.0,
        ),
        Text(
          title,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: AppTheme.subTitleATextStyle,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
  );
}
```

**The animation called from**

```
void buttonHandler() {
    _controller.forward();
    Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
      _controller.reverse();
    });
    Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
      print("something");
    });
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to add click event on grid item not on parent widget. Grid item is createGridItem

Comment: got it, so move the click event inside the gird item and will it handle the scaling/animation too ? I have inserted the click event in the gird item. where should I change then?

Comment: Update your code

Comment: I tried updating but still I can't seem to find it works out.

Comment: What you tried please update your code here

Answer (score 0):

Passing position to check which index has been tapped.

```dart
  Widget createGridItem(int position) {
    var icondata = Icons.add;
    var title = "";

    switch (position) {
      case 0:
        icondata = Icons.pie_chart;
        break;
      case 1:
        icondata = Icons.perm_device_info;
        break;

      default:
        icondata;
    }

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => buttonHandler(position),
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: 1,
        child: homeEnabledButtons(
          context,
          title,
          icondata,
          () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void buttonHandler(int position) {
    print("button handler $position");
    // _controller.forward();
    // Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
    //   _controller.reverse();
    // });
    // Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
    //   print("something");
    // });
  }

  Widget homeEnabledButtons(
      BuildContext context, String title, IconData icon, Function fun) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 10.0,
      // color: color,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Icon(
            icon,
            // color: primaryColor,
            size: 100.0,
          ),
          Text(
            title,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            // style: AppTheme.subTitleATextStyle,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
    );
  }
```